# How to drop tables with cyclic foreign keys in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables, Parent and Child. The column Parent.favorite_child has a foreign key constraint pointing to Child.id. And the column Child.parent has a foreign key constraint pointing to Parent.id.

Now here's the weird part. I'm trying to drop my Child table, which **contains no records**, but MySQL is giving me the error:

```
ERROR 1217: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
SQL Statement:
drop table `mydatabase`.`Child`
```

Why is MySQL throwing this error? There are literally no records in the Child table with which anything could be pointing to or from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first drop the foreign key on the parent table before you can delete the child table:

```
ALTER TABLE `Parent` DROP FOREIGN KEY `Parent_ibfk_1` ;
```

Comment: Thanks. Although I found `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;` worked even faster.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try dropping the foreign key constraint first

you might also want to try the command "show engine innodb status" - it may indicate if there is some leftover problem from when the tables had data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the Foreign key constraints from your table.

> try to do this as shown in image
>   [u could see that there are foreign key constraints in yellow shading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ic6NS.png)
>
> just right click on that key section and delete the foreign key like this.
>   [inside red section the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zYoq.png) and after that click okk to delete foreign key and that's it now you can delete the column by using simple
>       `AlTER table table_name drop column column_name;`

thank you.