# Database design - associative entities

Tags: database, many-to-many, entity, modeling, associative

I'm currently designing a database model and I've come across an issue, where I'd like some more input on what's considered the proper way of doing things.

In the example below I have two tables, Persons and Roles.
Now 1 person may be assigned 0 or more roles.
This is pretty straight forward with a many-to-many relationship, but the tricky part comes when you want to allow the user to select which role he is currently "operating" as.

Say the user got a selection of 5 roles to choose from, and depending on which role he currently has chosen, the application will present him with different views / menus / buttons / etc.

I see two solutions here:

1: (See top part of image linked below)

In the persons table, you include a nullable FK to the many-to-many relationship (the association entity).

From Wikipedia on [Associative entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_Entities)

It seems ok for "other entities" to reference this relationship. I'm just not entirely sure if this includes the Roles and Persons entities.

What I like about this design is that it's pretty easy to get a list of all allowed roles for a person, and then you simply point to one of those allowed roles, saying "you're the current/active one". This also feels like a good way to make sure that the user can only have a role as current, if he has access to the role... Only, I also see potential disaster here:
What if, the FK in the persons table references that relationship of another user. The DB design would allow this. It would only be code that prevents it.

2: (See bottom part of image linked below)

I keep the associative entity simple, and instead I have FK in persons table that points to a specific role in the Roles table.

The problem here is that I get even less help from the DB design with ensuring that the "current role" of a person, is a role that is actually "allowed".

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpYiL.png)

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated =)

UPDATE: I'll include another variation of the same issue.

Two entities: WorkOrders and Sites

- 1 Site may have access to many Work orders
- 1 WorkOrder may be accessed by many Sites

So we have a many-to-many relationship

The issue: How do we best store in database which Site is the Owner of a work order, when there can only be 1 Site that Owns a work order.

Do we have "OwnerSiteId" as a column in the WorkOrder table, or would it be ok to reference the many-to-many relationship instead, saying "that one" is the owner.

Comment: similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652152/mysql-circular-dependency-in-foreign-key-constraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your requirement is that 
 **One person can have many roles but only can have one active role** 
if yes than your both designs have following pros and cons

- **Design 1. Having key of ROLE table in the PERSON table**  pros: it will reduce on join hence cost will be reduced on database operation. Cons: You can assign the user a role that is never been in his allowed list.

- **Design 2. Having key of Associate Entity table in the PERSON table**   pros:PERSON will be assigned only those ROLES which are allowed for him. Cons: One additional join cost than first approach.

**Conclusion:** if I were you I will go for design 1 and ensure the role assignment from application.

Answer (score 0):

Store the current role together with other session data.

Comment: Yes, for this problem here I can see that might be a solution. Only I see this issue arise in other variations as well.

Example:

We have two other entities, WorkOrders and Sites.

A WorkOrder is owned by 1 site, and may be shared with several other sites.

Here you get the issue over again. You have several Sites that should have access to the work order, but only 1 of them is the "owner"

Comment: @TrondBlomholmKvamme Yes, but all of those references are *transient* and should not be stored "formally" in the database: It's all session stuff. If it's necessary to store "current" data, you would simply store it as a column of the entity. Otherwise, consider following Oswald's advice.